# What is block-linear allocation/addressing/layout?

Tags: cuda, gpu, textures

I see around the web in CUDA developer communities, when it comes to "texture cache", people are talking about "block linear". Can anyone please clarify and explain this term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block linear is a (not so often used) term referring to the opaque internal memory layout used in CUDA arrays. This is ordered ("block linear") to perform better in the texture cache, where spatial data locality is typically better suited to  the applications which the texture and surface hardware is designed for (i.e. rendering).

Comment: Why do you call it "opaque"? because  there is no documentation about that?

Comment: Yes, it isn't documented, isn't user accessible and isn't necessarily even constant across different hardware versions.

Comment: Thanks for extra inputs. With your permission I will edit and add them into your answer for ....

Comment: By the way, different "hardware versions" means different architectures?

Comment: I don't think that comment really adds anything extra to the answer to your original question, so I rejected the edit.